# Detect iPhone Volume Button Up Press?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, volume, avsystemcontroller

Is there a notification that I can listen to that will tell me when an iPhone's volume is turned **up**?

I know about the `AVSystemController_SystemVolumeDidChangeNotification`, but it is essential that the notification only be triggered when the volume has been turned up, not up or down.

Secondly, how can I hide the translucent view that appears when the volume up button is pressed, showing the system's volume?  **Camera+** has implemented this.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There is no documented way to to this, but you can use this workaround. Register for `AVSystemController_SystemVolumeDidChangeNotification` notification and add an `MPVolumeView` which will prevent the system volume view from showing up.

```
MPVolumeView *volumeView = [[MPVolumeView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(-100, 0, 10, 0)];
[volumeView sizeToFit];
[self.view addSubview:volumeView];
```

And don't forget to start an Audio Session

```
AudioSessionInitialize(NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
AudioSessionSetActive(true);
```

In This case, the `MPVolumeView` is hidden from the user.

As for checking if volume up or down was pressed, just grab the current application's volume

```
float volumeLevel = [[MPMusicPlayerController applicationMusicPlayer] volume];
```

and compare it with new volume after the button was pressed in notification callback

If you don't want to do it by yourself, there's a drop-in class available in github

https://github.com/blladnar/RBVolumeButtons

Comment: One thing I've noticed about using this method is that if I have another app playing music in the background (or potentially if you were already playing music in the app where you were doing this detection), that I would stop receiving notifications and the volume buttons would go back to just changing the volume of the music playing in the background =/

Comment: `[[MPMusicPlayerController applicationMusicPlayer] volume]` has been deprecated since iOS 7.

Answer (score 37):

If you want an event you can register a listener on the "outputVolume" property:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    AVAudioSession* audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];

    [audioSession setActive:YES error:nil];
    [audioSession addObserver:self
                    forKeyPath:@"outputVolume"
                       options:0
                       context:nil];
}

-(void) observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {

    if ([keyPath isEqual:@"outputVolume"]) {
        NSLog(@"volume changed!");
    }
}
```

Comment: I have looked at so many places over stackoverflow and this is the only one using non-deprecated methods and strings to get this done.

Comment: The problem with this solution is that if the outputVolume is already max and they press the + button, the callback doesn't happen.

Comment: this solution is really nice, but ray is right :( is it possible to reset the value programatically to 0?

Comment: How would I be able to have the action be called also when the volume is max?

Comment: @AustinT @donmarkusi You could try reading the current volume, then setting it back to (max - 1) if it's at the max. Look at `UISlider` and `setValue:animated:` to set it for `UIControlEventTouchUpInside`.

Comment: Hey @JaredH, would it be possible to change the volume to a preset value if the user changes the volume up or down? I want that the volume stay in the same place no matter what the user does.

Comment: this is not fired when volume is full and press high volume key and same when no volume and press low volume key. is there any solution?

Comment: this line is crucial: `[audioSession setActive:YES error:nil]`. without it you can't observe change.

Comment: is it worked in iOS simulator ? is not working for me in simulator.

Comment: Don't forget to remove the observer with `[audioSession removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"outputVolume"]`

Answer (score 3):

I solved this problem by adding own target/action for UISlider placed inside `MPVolumeView`. So it's possible to catch volume change events and determine what button was pressed. Here's [github repo](https://github.com/VitalyTimofeev/VTVolumeButtonsObserver) with implementation of this approach.
It works fine with iOS 7 and above, no deprecation warnings and no rejection from Apple.

Answer (score 1):

In order to distinguish volume action:  **INSTEAD OF** (in observeValue guard)

```
temp != 0.5
```

**USE** for only volume up

```
temp > 0.5
```

and only detect volume down:

```
temp < 0.5
```

This solution below will print if either volume up or down are pressed.

```
import AVFoundation
import MediaPlayer

override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()
  let volumeView = MPVolumeView(frame: CGRect.zero)
  for subview in volumeView.subviews {
    if let button = subview as? UIButton {
      button.setImage(nil, for: .normal)
      button.isEnabled = false
      button.sizeToFit()
    }
  }
  UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.addSubview(volumeView)
  UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.sendSubview(toBack: volumeView)
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
  super.viewWillAppear(animated)
  AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "outputVolume", options: NSKeyValueObservingOptions.new, context: nil)
  do { try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true) }
  catch { debugPrint("\(error)") }   
}

override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
  super.viewDidDisappear(animated)
  AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: "outputVolume")
  do { try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(false) } 
  catch { debugPrint("\(error)") }
}

override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
  guard let key = keyPath else { return }
  switch key {
    case "outputVolume":
      guard let dict = change, let temp = dict[NSKeyValueChangeKey.newKey] as? Float, temp != 0.5 else { return }
      let systemSlider = MPVolumeView().subviews.first { (aView) -> Bool in
        return NSStringFromClass(aView.classForCoder) == "MPVolumeSlider" ? true : false
      } as? UISlider
      systemSlider?.setValue(0.5, animated: false)
      guard systemSlider != nil else { return }
      debugPrint("Either volume button tapped.")
    default:
      break
  } 
}
```