# Volume Detection In IOS 6

Tags: iphone, ios6

I am creating a app in which when the app is in background and user changes the volume in iPhone app should came to know about it.
Any ideas or clues?

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions

{
    //self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];

    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    AudioSessionInitialize(NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);

    AudioSessionSetActive(true);

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
     addObserver:self
     selector:@selector(volumeChanged:)
     name:@"AVSystemController_SystemVolumeDidChangeNotification"
     object:nil];

    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    LoginVC *login=[[LoginVC alloc]initWithNibName:@"LoginVC" bundle:nil];

    self.navigate=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:login];

    [self.window addSubview:navigate.view];

    [login release];

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;


}

- (void)volumeChanged:(NSNotification *)notification
{

    float volume =
    [[[notification userInfo]
      objectForKey:@"AVSystemController_AudioVolumeNotificationParameter"]
     floatValue];


    NSLog(@"chfi");



  // Do stuff with volume
}
```

I Have Used This code But its not getting Called.

Comment: Can't do it. Can you explain what you're trying to do more generally? There might be an alternative solution.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I just wanted to detect the hardware volume detection  when the app is in background.

Comment: Why do you want to do that? There may be a different way to achieve the same effect.

Comment: I was wrong. It looks like it might be possible. Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3651252/how-to-get-audio-volume-level-and-volume-changed-notifications-on-ios-4

Comment: It is a process in the app when the app is in the background and user changes the volume of a Iphone i had to send a message to the server thats why.

Comment: Thanks for the link .I had tried that its not working in IOS 6.0

Answer (score 0):

You can set a listener. When volume changed, the call back method will be getting called.

Comment: As far as I know, there isn’t a way to do it directly, so I listen to a volume change notification.

Comment: Have you Implemented this when app is in background and in IOS 6.0

Comment: <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9660445/detect-iphone-volume-button-up-press>