# Capture picture on volume up custom camera overlay ios

Tags: iphone, ios, camera-overlay

I am doing an app which take pictures and uploads to server. I am using custom camera overlay, I am showing it using

```
[self presentModalViewController:self.picker animated:NO];
```

I want to capture picture on pressing volume key up also. I tried this code but no benefit

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(takePicture:)name:@"AVSystemController_SystemVolumeDidChangeNotification" object:nil];
```

Kindly help me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you resolve the issue? I'm currently struggling with the same one

Answer (score 1):

There is a drop in library that you can use found on Github here: https://github.com/blladnar/RBVolumeButtons

If you want to roll your own see the accepted answer here (where I got the previous link): [Detect iPhone Volume Button Up Press?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9660445/detect-iphone-volume-button-up-press)

Comment: I tried these but this does not work in UIImagePicker but it works in ViewController.