# AVAudioSession's OutputVolume never changes

Tags: ios, avaudiosession

There are plenty of questions and answers on SO that say `[AVAudioSession sharedInstance].outputVolume` is the only way to detect a device's volume. But it doesn't seem to work quite right. `outputVolume` never changes, though it is correct when it is first set (at application launch).

Am I doing it wrong? I don't know what else to do besides reading the value of `outputVolume`. My instincts would tell me this was a bug, if it wasn't for the fact that [other people](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22601280) seem to be doing it just fine. I also tested it on iOS 7 and 8, so it's not an iOS 8 bug. I reproduced the same thing in a small test project, so nothing in my project is interfering with it.

Also: I am well aware of the difference between ringer-volume and sound-volume. I changed both, and the reported volume still did not change.

Here's the function I used in my test project:

```
- (void)checkVolume
{
    float volume = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance].outputVolume;

    NSLog(@"Volume: %f", volume);

    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(2.0 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^
    {
        [self checkVolume];
    });
}
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Use KVO, and make sure to activate the `sharedInstance`:

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:YES error:nil];
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"outputVolume" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:nil];
```

Comment: I see. The secret was in the line `[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:YES error:nil];`. THIS is what I have to call before `outputVolume` will change. Thank you very much

Comment: I had to look at a lot of bogus SO answers before I found this one. It should be rated much higher.

Comment: I'm still having an issue where KVO on outputVolume seems to stop working after my app loses focus (so basically when my audio session is reset), even if I re-register the observer.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue as well. You need to start your audio session and also give it a category:

```
let session = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()

do {
  try session.setCategory(.playback, options: .mixWithOthers)
  try session.setActive(true)
} catch {
  print("Unable to start audio session: \(error)")
}
```

Your audio session's output volume should pick  up volume changes now.

Answer (score 0):

I am finding I need to actually output sound in order for [AVAudioSession sharedInstance].outputVolume to be accurate.

In other words - [AVAudioSession sharedInstance].outputVolume is a little flakey - you need to play audio for it to return the correct volume.

Comment: This post doesn't look like an attempt to answer this question. Every post here is expected to be an explicit attempt to *answer* this question; if you have a critique or need a clarification of the question or another answer, you can [post a comment](//stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) (like this one) directly below it. Please remove this answer and create either a comment or a new question. See: [Ask questions, get answers, no distractions](//stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: You will find on the internet many people saying [AVAudioSession sharedInstance].outputVolume does not work, and this is the reason why at least sometimes.

Comment: The question is why getting the volume does not work right. The answer is you need to play sound to get it to work.

Comment: I found this answer helpful

Answer (score 0):

I checked in iOS 12:

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:YES error:nil];
float vol = [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] outputVolume];
NSLog(@"outputVolume: %f", vol);
```