# xamarin forms sound control not in sync with device

Tags: audio, xamarin

I am new to ios developement, using xamarin forms to develop online audio player. I am done with my app with my own progress bar which sets the player volume but it does not sync with device volume.

e.g when you reduce/increase sound in device, update the same on app progress bar. 
I am sure, i have to register and listen output volume of the device but don't know which api/event i need to use.

Answer (score 1):

here you go http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/140333#Comment_140333
and

https://github.com/twenzel/Xamarin/blob/master/Utils/VolumeButton/VolumeButtonHandler.cs

[AVAudioSession's OutputVolume never changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24872409/avaudiosessions-outputvolume-never-changes)