# How to track to know action iPhone's volume when user down or up volume in swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift

I would like to know about how to control IPhone's volume control in swift 3 when you have been down volume or up volume? I want to control it with my UISlider Volume to make it the same IPhone event.

Thank you!

Comment: Is [this question/answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28471481/swift-detect-volume-button-press) useful to your case?

Comment: yes, sure, I will implement it if user make down or up volume to call another func if I can know how can I track it. it is very useful no need user unlock their phone. thanks

Comment: Glad to help, if that was the answer for your question, I recommend to close it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To control the volume, just drag a view in Interface Builder (not View Controller, just View) then at the custom class type MPVolumeView. When you run the app on a real device (in simulator it does not show), you will be able to control the volume.

Comment: ok I will try this idea. if it works will check your answer as correct. thanks

Comment: @Kristoff, did it work? If it did not, try to connect an IBOutlet of the MPVolumeView and reply.

Comment: Can I have any screenshot ? how ? or missed something ?

Comment: @Kristoff, just drag a view in the view controller, and at the custom class of the view type MPVolumeView. Then, create a new Swift file and a view controller class, assign it to the view controller and create an IBOutlet here. There is no screenshot as it is not visible in storyboard or simulator, just on a real device.

Comment: Oh yes, it showed but I can not swipe it. what I want to do is I can use phone control and user can swipe control also (both). Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "I can not swipe it" ? And could you, please, explain better what you want to do?

Comment: yes, Now it's working well. Thank you so much for help

Comment: I'm happy to hear that! Anytime!