# Override volume up in swift, iOS 10 to take a picture

Tags: ios, swift, camera, volume

I would like to use volume up / volume down to shoot a picture inside my app (coded in **Swift** 3.2), in the same way iOS built in Camera app does.
Is there an easy way of doing that? It would be great if it was code only (no storyboards involved)
Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detect volume button press](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28471481/detect-volume-button-press)

Answer (score 2):

There is no straightforward API's available for now. But below workaround would be working for your condition.

- Listen to `AVAudioSession` keypath `outputVolume` and when there is new value you can capture a photo.

---

```
import AVFoundation

var audioSession = AVAudioSession()
try audioSession.setActive(true)
audioSession.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "outputVolume", options: NSKeyValueObservingOptions.new, context: nil)


func observeValueForKeyPath(keyPath: String, ofObject object: AnyObject, change: [NSObject : AnyObject], context: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>) {
    if keyPath == "outputVolume"{
        // capture photo here.
    }
}
```

Comment: FYI. For Swift 5, the correct function signature is:
`override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?)`