# Detect hardware volume button press when volume not changed

Tags: ios, swift, audio

I need to detect the sound volume button click. Solution in [Detect volume button press](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28471481/detect-volume-button-press) and  used by me work only when sounds volume changed.  I need to detect sound volume button click. For example when the sound has max level and the user clicks up level button this solution was not work.

```
 let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
    self.obs = audioSession.observe( \.outputVolume ) { (av, change) in
    print("volume \(av.outputVolume)")
 }
```

Are there any other working solutions to detect a sound volume button press?

Comment: Whether or not you find a way to detect it, you may want to check Apple's [Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/) - specifically:  **2.5.9** *Apps that alter or disable the functions of standard switches, such as the Volume Up/Down and Ring/Silent switches, or other native user interface elements or behaviors will be rejected.*

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Detect volume button press](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28471481/detect-volume-button-press)

Comment: I do not want to  alter or disable the functions of standard volume.  I need only detect click,  in case when volume not changed.

Comment: Instagram app detecting volume button click in this case(when volume is max)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28471481/detect-volume-button-press   in this solution detecting change sound volume and not work when volume not changed. for example when sound is max and user click up

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
let volumeView = MPVolumeView(frame: CGRect.zero)
self.view.addSubview(volumeView)
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(volumeChanged(_:)), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "AVSystemController_SystemVolumeDidChangeNotification"), object: nil)
```

This will get called every press regardless of volume level

```
@objc func volumeChanged(_ notification: NSNotification) {
    if let volume = notification.userInfo!["AVSystemController_AudioVolumeNotificationParameter"] as? Float {
        print("volume: \(volume)")
    }
}
```

output:

```
volume: 0.8125
volume: 0.875
volume: 0.9375
volume: 1.0
volume: 1.0
volume: 1.0
volume: 1.0
```

Comment: this observer never called for IPhoneXR and IOS 13.3

Comment: In simulator or on an actual device?

Comment: on my  real device

Comment: And you have it implemented correctly?  Could you create a pastebin or similar of your relevant code?  I don't have an XR but I'm scratching my head that to why it would not work on it while it's fine on an 11 Pro.

Comment: Thank You, its works. I made mistake in implementation

Comment: Small addition: volumeView has possibility bee hide and it works. I have to control AVSystemController_AudioVolumeChangeReasonNotificationParameter. because I have wrong call of observer

Comment: Best solution across other topics at StackOverFlow (> than volume 1.0) also being detected.

Comment: Don't forget to import MediaPlayer at the top.