# Listen to volume button presses the correct way (iOS 15)

Tags: ios, swift, avaudioplayer, avaudiosession

I have used

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(volumeChanged(_:)), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "AVSystemController_SystemVolumeDidChangeNotification"), object: nil)
```

in the past to listen to volume control changes however this no longer works in iOS 15.

This alternative code below only works well if you don't care about a user pressing the volume up when at max volume. However, I do want to know every time the button is pressed.

```
AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "outputVolume", options: NSKeyValueObservingOptions.new, context: nil)
```

What is the correct way to listen to the user pressing the volume control button even when the volume is at its max/min?

Comment: have you applied the solution? is it fixed?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use mediaplayer liabrary for it.

just `import MediaPlayer`

```
let volumeView = MPVolumeView(frame: CGRect.zero)
self.view.addSubview(volumeView)
```

You will get event of every press regardless of volume level

Comment: its not working in iOS 15.1.1

Answer (score 1):

I think this is duplicate of [Detect hardware volume button press when volume not changed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59718815/detect-hardware-volume-button-press-when-volume-not-changed).

They simply `import MediaPlayer` And then:

```
let volumeView = MPVolumeView(frame: CGRect.zero)
self.view.addSubview(volumeView)
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(volumeChanged(_:)), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "AVSystemController_SystemVolumeDidChangeNotification"), object: nil)

@objc func volumeChanged(_ notification: NSNotification) {
 if let volume = notification.userInfo!["AVSystemController_AudioVolumeNotificationParameter"] as? Float {
     print("volume: \(volume)")
 }
}
```

This will output:

```
volume: 0.8125
volume: 0.875
volume: 0.9375
volume: 1.0
volume: 1.0
volume: 1.0
volume: 1.0
```

Remember to import MediaPlayer.

Also [Jayesh Patel’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69535332/12659689) is short and accurate, so you may use that too.

Comment: It seems that this notification is not being called on iOS 15.0.2.
Does anyone know what could be the issue?