# Detect if volume down button is pressed twice OBJC iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to call a function if the volume down button is pressed twice in the same second, is that possible or is it impossible?!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Detect volume button press](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28471481/detect-volume-button-press)

Comment: @Willeke no it isnt the same!

Comment: What OS is this question about? iOS? macOS? Other? Show what you have tried so far. Clearly explain what issues you are having. The link by Willeke gives you a good starting point at a minimum.

Comment: @HangarRash iOS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The link by Willeke gives you a good starting point at a minimum.
if your device is iPhone with OC, use AVFoundation and MediaPlayer can monitored the volume change.
1、

```
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
#import <MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h>
```

2、

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) MPVolumeView* volumeView;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UISlider* volumeSlider;
```

3、

```
NSError* error = nil;
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient error:&error];
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"error setting category:%@", error.localizedDescription);
    }
    
    _volumeView = [[MPVolumeView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    [self.view addSubview:self.volumeView];

    // 找到MPVolumeView上的UISlider
    for (UIView *view in [self.volumeView subviews]){
        if ([view isKindOfClass:[UISlider class]]) {
            self.volumeSlider = (UISlider *)view;
            break;
        }
    }
    
    [self.volumeSlider addTarget:self action:@selector(volumeChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

4、

```
- (void)dealloc {
    [self.volumeSlider removeTarget:self action:@selector(volumeChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
}

- (void)volumeChanged:(UISlider *)sender {
    NSLog(@"%.2f", sender.value);
}
```

You can listen to the volume change in the method, and if you want to make consecutive clicks for 1 second, you need to set a timestamp as an anchor.
But there are some problems with this method:

1. Removed the default volume adjustment UI of the system, and the new iOS system can not use MPVolumeView;
2. When the screen is locked, the APP cannot take effect when it is inactive;
3. Different iOS versions may have different effects.